How to define dom(R) in ZF(C) Set Theory?
I have found way to introduce new symbols to ZF(C) Set Theory in Set Theory written by Kunen.
How to introduce new symbols
For example, we can introduce 2-ary predicate $\subset$ with definition $\forall x\forall y(x\subset y\leftrightarrow\forall t(t\in x\rightarrow t\in y))$.
However, I find it hard to define dom(R), R is a 2-ary relation.
At first, I regarded it as an 1-ary function. But it occured to me that using "dom(R)" in a formula indicates R is a 2-ary relation. So how can I define it?

If binary relations between $X$ and $Y$ are defined in the standard way as subsets of $X×Y$, then $\text{dom}(R)$ can be defined by $∀ R, (∀ x, x ∈ \text{dom}(R) ⇔ (∃ y, (x, y) ∈ R))$. (Using the comprehension axiom, you can prove $∀ R, ∃! D, ∀ x, x ∈ D ⇔ (∃ y, (x, y) ∈ R)$ in ZF.)
You seem disturbed by the fact that this allows speaking of $\text{dom}(2)$ or $\text{dom}(ℝ)$ in spite of $2$ and $ℝ$ not being relations. The answer is that in set theory, everything is a set, and it is only informal convention to use operators such as $\text{dom}$ only on certain types of objects such as relations. This is sufficient for studying axioms such as the axiom of choice and large cardinals. It is however quite inconvenient for formalizing mathematics in proof assistants, which is one reason why most proof assistants are based on type theory instead.
